What does the $\pi_r^{-1}$ notation mean in the Frobenius Map in CKKS Scheme?
I read the Homomorphic Encryption Paper, TensorFHE. On page 5, they explain the Frobenius Map function that is used for the ciphertext rotation in CKKS Scheme.
It said:
For every $a^{(i)}=(a^{(i)}_j)$ for $j \in [0, N-1]$ in $a^{(i)}$ for $i \in [0,l]$
it generates $a'^{(i)}=(a^{(i)}_{\pi^{−1}_r(j)})$ for $j \in [0,N−1]$
where $\pi_r(x) = ([5^r(2x+1))]_{2N} - 1)/2$
...
I don't understand what $\pi_r^{-1}(j)$ means. Is that an inverse of the $\pi_r(j)$ function? If yes, then how can I calculate its inverse?

Yes, it means the inverse which can be computed as
$$\pi^{-1}_r(j)=([5^{-r}(2j+1)]_{2N}-1)/2.$$

$/2{}{}{}{}{}{}$ ?

@kelalaka Yes. Note that $[5^{-r}(2j+1)]_{2N}$ is an odd number.

Thank you! I was wondering why the author didn't write the inverse in their paper
